# BitBake: How to use shell script content as body of pkg_postinst or pkg_preinst functions?

Tags: function, file, recipe, bitbake

I want to add the contents of a shell script into the body of pkg_preinst_${PN} or pkg_postinst_${PN} function (BitBake recipe of a software package).

For example, let's consider this "PREINST" shell script:

```
$ cat PREINST
#! /bin/sh
chmod +x /usr/bin/mybin
```

Executing a simple 'cat' command inside pkg_preinst function doesn't work:

```
pkg_preinst_${PN}() {
    cat ${S}/path/to/PREINST
}
```

In this way, the contents for the .spec file for the generated rpm package are not the expected:

```
%pre
cat /Full/Path/To/Variable/S/path/to/PREINST
```

As you can see, %pre section doesn't include real contents of PREINST file, just includes the 'cat' command.

Is it possible to include the contents of PREINST file into the generated .spec file in some way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found a file poky/meta/classes/package_rpm.bbclass where the method write_specfile is defined. That method seems to read the value of a key "pkg_preinst" which value seems to be the preinst script. But I am unable to modify the value of that key to change its value. This: d.setVar("pkg_preinst", "hello world")) doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this issue by prepending this code to the do_package task:

```
do_package_prepend() {
    PREINST_path = "${S}/${MYMODULE}/PREINST"
    POSTINST_path = "${S}/${MYMODULE}/POSTINST"
    PREINST = open(PREINST_path, "r")
    POSTINST = open(POSTINST_path, "r")
    d.setVar("pkg_preinst", PREINST.read())
    d.setVar("pkg_postinst", POSTINST.read())
}
```

It modifies "pkg_preinst" and "pkg_postinst" keys in 'd' global dictionary with the content of each PREINST and POSTINST file as value. Now it works! :)